# Smooth function which is not continuous

Tags: functional-analysis, topological-vector-spaces

I have seen it mentioned that in certain infinite dimensional topological vector spaces it is possible to have a smooth curve which is not continuous, but I've never seen an explicit example. Can anybody point me towards a reference for this?

Comment: Isn't continuous included in the defintion of smooth?

Comment: This seems to be an oxymoron: smooth function is waaaay more than merely continuous, but undoubtedly *it is* continuous.

Comment: Smooth implies continuous is true in finite dimensions, but apparently not necessarily in infinite dimensions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The mentioner might have been thinking of discontinuous linear maps on infinite-dimensional topological vector spaces.  You can read about the construction of such functions at [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discontinuous_linear_map#General_existence_theorem).  The construction relies on the axiom of choice.

I am not an expert on notions of differentiability in infinite-dimensional spaces, but any linear function is well-approximated by a linear function (itself!).  So I believe that a discontinuous linear function has a [Fréchet derivative](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fr%C3%A9chet_derivative).

**Edit:** Christopher Wong explains below that the function will be [Gateaux differentiable](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/G%C3%A2teaux_derivative) but *not* Fréchet differentiable.

Comment: It will be Gateaux differentiable, but since the function itself is not continuous, it cannot have a Frechet derivative, which is required to be continuous.

Comment: Yes, I think that in the context where I've seen this they've been using the Gateaux derivative (but not using that name). Thanks!

Comment: @Christopher Thank you!  I've added a correction.